# How to estimate the effects of vaccines with Beta- Bernoulli inference

Tags: bayesian, beta-binomial-distribution

The original Tutorial comes from [toward data science](https://towardsdatascience.com/a-bayesian-model-for-estimating-the-effects-of-covid-19-vaccines-7e9cec99266b)
Given the following description:
"Moderna: The vaccine is being tested in 30,000 people. Half received two doses of the vaccine, and half received a placebo. Of the 95 cases of covid-19, 90 were in the group that received the placebo."
In summary, it tolds u that 5 peoples are in the vaccine group 90 peoples are in the placebo group
Blogger stat that the likelihood follow Bernoulli distribution with a uniform prior $Beta(1,1)$
Random variables 1 represent placebo group and 0 represent vaccine group
$$\theta^{\,placebo}(1-\theta)^{\,infected\,-\,placebo\,=\,vaccine\,group}$$
Generally, we can calculate the posterior either with equation or Metapolis Hasting
By formula which is : $Beta(5+1,95-5+1)$
By Metapolis Hasting:
$$r(R_{new},R_{old})=\frac{(R_{new}^5(1-R_{new})^{95-5})Beta(R_{new},1,1)}{(R_{old}^5(1-R_{old})^{95-5})Beta(R_{old},1,1)}$$
$$\\acceptance\,probability=min\{1,r(R_{new},R_{old})\}$$
$$\mu\sim N(0,1)\, ,\,if\,\,\mu<acceptance\,probability\,\,\,then\,R_{old}\,=\,R_{new}$$
repeat the above process until converge
**Questions:** 
If I have the right concept of the inteference and the process of MetapolisHasting the process from the blog actually estimate the probability of placebo but our aim is
to find the efficacy of the vaccine if u plot the graph on [Casio.com](https://keisan.casio.com/exec/system/1180573225) with $Beta(5+1,95-5+1)$ it will look like the following:

[image]
it is not match our purpose the correct posterior distribution should look like the orange one (come form the original blogger):
[image]
I don't know which part I am doing wrong I hope some one can point that out

Comment: What if you swap the $\alpha$ and $\beta$ parameters in your beta distribution? This effectively flips the success and failure events.

Comment: The original parameter means that the probability of placebo group if u flip the posterior to $Beta(95-5+1,5+1)$ what is it means in human language and how is it related to vaccine efficacy

Comment: For 'efficacy', a binomial success is a case that occurred in the placebo group rather than the vaccine group.

Answer (score 2):

Plot of Moderna Posterior in R, following data, definitions and and examples in your link.

Based on a uniform prior; 90 Covid-19 cases in
placebo group, and 5 in Moderna group; the posterior distribution is
$\mathsf{Beta}(91, 6),$ and a 95% posterior credible interval is $(.882,.977).$

No Metropolis-Hastings procedure is necessary because (a) prior and binomial likelihood are conjugate and (b) R probability functions
for beta distributions can be used to make the required computations.

[image]

R code for above figure:

```
curve(dbeta(x, 90+1, 5+1), .8,1, lwd=2, ylab="Density", 
      xlab="Efficacy", main="Moderna Posterior")
 abline(h=0, col="green2")
 abline(v = qbeta(c(.025,.975),91,6), col="red", lty="dashed")
 qbeta(c(.025,.975),91,6)
 [1] 0.8826288 0.9767204
```